# Выделение памяти

Tags: c++, c, память, malloc, calloc

Подскажите, как сделать выделение памяти через `malloc` и `calloc` вместо `new` и `delete`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PrintArr(int**, int n1, int m1);
void SearchN(int**, int n1, int m1);

void main()
{
    int n, m;
    int **arrA;
    do
    //Проверка на размерность массива
    {
        printf("\nVvedite kolichestvo strok n: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        printf("\nVvedite kolichestvo stolbzov m: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &m);
    } while ((m<1) && (n<1));

    //Выделение памяти
    if (!(arrA = new int*[n]))
    {
        printf("\nNe hvataet pamyati\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        if (!(*(arrA + i) = new int[m]))
        {
            printf("\nNe hvataet pamati\n");
            arrA = NULL;
            exit(0);
        }

    //Ввод элементов массива
    printf("\nVvedite elementi massiva\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d][%d]", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", *(arrA + i) + j);
        }
    }
    PrintArr(arrA, n, m);
    puts("\n\n");
    SearchN(arrA, n, m);
    //освобождение памяти

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        delete[](*(arrA + i));
    }
    delete[]  arrA;
    _getch();
}

//Поиск нулевых чисел в столбце
void SearchN(int** arr, int n1, int m1)
{
    int t;
    for (int j = 0; j<m1; j++)
    {
        t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<n1; i++)
        {
            if (*(*(arr + i) + j) == 0)
            {
                t++;
            }
        }
        if (t == 0)
        {
            printf("\n stolbez nomer [%d] ne soderzit ni odnogo nylevogo elementa\n", j + 1);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n stolbez nomer [%d] soderzit nylevie elementi\n", j + 1);
        }
    }
}

//Функция вывода на печать 
void PrintArr(int **arr, int n1, int m1)
{
    puts("Vvedenni massiv = ");
    for (int i = 0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        for (int j = 0; j<m1; j++)
            printf("%5d", *(*(arr + i) + j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы сделать выделение памяти через malloc и calloc вместо new и delete нужно использовать  malloc и calloc вместо new и delete. Поясните что конкретно не получается. Написать `malloc(n*sizeof(int))`/`calloc(n,sizeof(int))`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6ewkz86d.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3f8w183e.aspx Крайне доступно. MSDN способна ответить по сути на все ваши вопросы, познавайте.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я, кстати, не помню, у нас при голосовании в + появляется предложение для ТС поставить галочку?

Comment: @alexolut К сожалению, не понял вопрос. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если ТС голосует за какой-то ответ на свой вопрос плюсом, то появляется уведомление "не забудьте отметить  верный ответ" или что-то подобное. Я не помню, где это видел, на ruSO или на другом сайте сети.

Comment: @alexolut Я не встречал подобного.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky проверьте на русскийЯзык.se. Вроде бы там недавно видел. Надо нам тоже такой функционал.

Answer (score 2):

Всё достаточно просто. Если речь только о выделении/освобождении памяти, то можно провести такие аналогии:

```
new T == malloc(sizeof(T))
new T[n] == malloc(sizeof(T) * n)
delete ptr == free(ptr)
delete [] ptr == free(ptr)
```

При этом возможно потребуется приведение типов, т.к. `malloc` возвращает `void*`, а `new T` - `T*`.

Comment: Опасные аналогии проводите, товарищ!

Comment: @ixSci с уточнением всё-таки.

Answer (score 1):

Позволю себе дополнить ответ [@alexolut](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut) - учтите, что при выделении памяти через `malloc`/`calloc` не происходит вызов конструкторов объектов, а при освобождении через `free` - не вызываются деструкторы. Поэтому в случае любого нетривиального типа вам придется создавать объекты самостоятельно с помощью размещающего `new`, а перед освобождением - вызывать деструкторы.

Кроме того, при любых типах, не являющихся типами POD (plain old data), не следует прибегать к функции `realloc`, так как после возможного переноса в памяти внутренние указатели могут стать недействительны.